# Laravel query fails but works in Mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel, date

I am new to Laravel and using the following query,

```sql
    DB::table("rates as rate")
            ->select("rate.category")
            ->where(DB::Raw("STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT( start_day, '/', start_month, '/', start_year ) ,'%d/%m/%Y' )"), ">=", '"'.$InFormat.'"')
            ->where(DB::Raw("STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT( end_day, '/', end_month, '/', end_year ) ,'%d/%m/%Y' )"), "<=", '"'.$OutFormat.'"')            
            ->where("rate.name", "=", $name)
            ->whereNull("rate.deleted_at")->get();
```

This query not running in Laravel But when I use DB::getQueryLog(),get the query and runs in mysql, it works fine.

I think the date is the issue. Please help me.

Regards,
Rekha

Comment: What error is output?

Comment: "This query not running" then you must have logs to tell you why?

Answer (score 0):

I think its because your config database's `strict mode` is `true`. make the field `false`.

you will find it in

```
config/database.php > connections > mysql > strict
```

Comment: Why do you think that? There are no error messages provided in the question, so how can you make that determination?

Comment: strict mode to false only set.But empty array returned.